# IOS 10 mobile audio.play() work unstable

Tags: ios, html, audio, playback

Here is my code :

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.play',function () {
play = $(this);
var stop = $('.stop');
contentId = play.attr('id');
nexttrack = nexttrackPlay(play);

if(!play.parent().hasClass('stop')) {
  if(song ==undefined){
    initAudio(play);
  }
  else
  {
    song.src = play.attr('audiourl');
    song.load();
  }

  playerInit(play);
  stop.each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('stop');
  });

  playAudio();
}
else{
  if(song.paused){
    playAudio();
  }
  else{
    stopAudio();
  }
}


 });

function initAudio(elem) {
var url = elem.attr('audiourl');
song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
console.log(song);
song.src = url;
song.preload = 'metadata';
song.load();
    song.addEventListener('play', function () {
  $('.play-play').addClass('stop');
  play.parent().addClass('stop');
  play.removeClass('pause');
  $('.button-play').addClass('stop');
      song.removeEventListener('play',function(){  });
},false);

song.addEventListener('pause', function () {
  play.addClass('pause');
  $('.play-play').removeClass('stop');
  $('.button-play').removeClass('stop');
  song.removeEventListener('play',function(){  });
},false);


}
  function playAudio() {
    song.load();
  song.play();
  }
  function stopAudio() {
    song.pause();
  }
```

On Android and desktop works perfectly but on IOS at first click don't work, when click on another song and then again at first it start playing.

Comment: We need a little bit more than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem and solution)
All thing was in headers, I sent headers with Content-type:application/octet-stream and this was a problem for IOS, then I change it to audio/mpeg and audio start loading.